# How to Union Different Types in Linq-2-Entity

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, union

I'm trying to get a result like a grid! With headers and values above. trying to do  this.

```
void Main()
{
    var ctx = dbContext;
    (from tQuestions in ctx.Questions
        select new 
        {
            a1_1 = (Object)tQuestions.HeaderCreationDate //varchar(max)(sometning like "Creation Date")
        }
    ).Union<Object>(from tAnswers in ctx.Answers
        select new{
        a1_1 = (Object)tAnswers.CreationDate //DateTime (something like "2018-05-24 00:00:00.000")
        }
    ).Dump();
}
```

And having this as result: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
void Main()
{
    var ctx = dbContext;
   (from tQuestion in ctx.Questions
        select new 
        {
            cod = (object)tQuestion.Id ,
            r1_1 = (object)tQuestion.R1_1 //varchar(max)(sometning like "Creation Date")
        }
    ).ToList().Concat(from tAnswer in ctx.Answers
        select new{
                      cod = (object)tAnswer.Id,
                      r1_1 = (object)tAnswer.CreationDate //DateTime (something like "2018-05-24 00:00:00.000")
                  }
   ).ToList().Dump();
}
```

Thanks community!!